# Run selenium jar on travis CI from protractor node_modules folder

Tags: javascript, selenium, protractor, travis-ci, e2e-testing

I am setting up Travis in order to execute e2e tests through protractor. 
On my `protractor.config.js` I have the following:

`seleniumServerJar: './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar'`

So actually it refers to the selenium jar included by default inside the `protractor` plugin.

Then I use the plugin `gulp-protractor` in order to execute the tests pointing to the right `protractor.config.js`.

Locally everything works like a charm.

But when trying to execute this on Travis, I am getting the following error:

> [18:59:15] I/launcher - Running 1 instances of WebDriver [18:59:15]
>   E/local - Error code: 135 [18:59:15] E/local - Error message: No
>   selenium server jar found at
>   /home/travis/build/quirimmo/Qprotractor/node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-3.5.0.jar.
>   Run 'webdriver-manager update' to download binaries.

Any idea why it looks like it cannot retrieve the jar from the node_modules subfolder please?

Here my `.travis.yml` configuration, which is actually pretty simple:

```
sudo: required
dist: trusty

addons:
  chrome: stable

language: node_js
node_js:
  - '6.11'

before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - sleep 3

install:
  - npm install

script:
  - echo "Triggered!"
  - gulp protractor-test
```

Thanks a lot, any help would be really appreciated!

**p.s. I already did it on other projects with Travis running manually the `webdriver-manager` and then pointing to the selenium address from the `protractor.config.js`, but I don't want that solution and I want to go on through the `seleniumServerJar` property, because in this way it will run everything alone without any need of starting manually the `webdriver-manager`**

Comment: Why don't you install webdriver-manager globally in your before_script?

Comment: Hi @TarunLalwani, first thanks a lot for your comment. I did try but with no luck. I get always the same error after. This solution is the one which works fine when then you execute the `webdriver-manager` manually and then you point to that URL from the `protractor.config.js`. Does it make sense?

Comment: Any sample repo you can give that I can play with?

Comment: Sure thanks @TarunLalwani. It's still under development but it's the one connected to Travis that I am talking about here. Try to clone it, create a branch, and if you start a PR you should trigger directly the same job on Travis: https://github.com/quirimmo/qprotractor
p.s. I think that at the moment you will trigger the job even just pushing on your branch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posting here the answer if this could be useful for someone else in the future. 
As explained very well in this link:

https://github.com/angular/protractor/issues/3225

You need to manually trigger the installation of the selenium server.

So in the `install` block of your travis file, you can simply add this:

```
install:
  - npm install
  - node_modules/protractor/bin/webdriver-manager update
```

And then inside the `protractor.config.js`, grab the current version of the installed selenium server:

```
const SELENIUM_FOLDER = './node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium';
const fs = require('fs');
let res, seleniumVersion;
fs.readdirSync(SELENIUM_FOLDER).forEach(file => {
    res = file.match(/selenium-server-standalone-(\d{1}.\d{1}.\d{1}).jar/i);
    if (res) {
        seleniumVersion = res[1];
    } 
})
if (!seleniumVersion) {
    throw new Error('No selenium server jar found inside your protractor node_modules subfolder');
}
```

And then execute it in this way:

```
seleniumServerJar: `./node_modules/protractor/node_modules/webdriver-manager/selenium/selenium-server-standalone-${seleniumVersion}.jar`
```

I hope this will help someone else avoiding to lose few hours of time against this issue!

Answer (score 1):

Fixed in your repo. You should change your `before_script` to below

```
before_script:
  - export DISPLAY=:99.0
  - sh -e /etc/init.d/xvfb start
  - sleep 3
  - npm install -g webdriver-manager
  - webdriver-manager update
  - webdriver-manager start &
  - sleep 3
```

And then in your `protactor.confg.js` add the `seleniumAddress`

```
exports.config = {
    seleniumAddress: 'http://127.0.0.1:4444/wd/hub/',
    specs: [
        './test/base-protractor.spec.js',
        './test/element-finder.spec.js',
        './test/element-array-finder.spec.js'
    ],
    onPrepare: function() {
        require('./index');
    }
};
```

Comment: Did you read the comments on github and did you read the question where I say: "I am already able to do that starting manually webdriver-manager and using selenium address as property?"

Comment: @quirimmo, Lol my bad. Give me few mins

Comment: No problem and thanks a lot for helping :) if you are interested in, and you would like, we could also go on collaborating in that project :)

Comment: @quirimmo, check the latest one in this https://github.com/quirimmo/Qprotractor/pull/5